# Privacy link from the footer of newsletter is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, newsletter

Recently I've got an Email newsletter for Stack Overflow in Russian and noticed that "Privacy" link in the letter's body footer is broken:

> [image: broken privacy]

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "broken", are you referring solely to the English lettering, or also that the link doesn't go to the right place?

Comment: @SOLO I don’t reflect localization issue here because I recently made a translation for the word “Privacy” via Transifex and I hope that next week letter will be fixed in that way. This issue is about wrong target for the link. And it can’t be fixed via translators, only by the developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix for this will be rolling out in the next build (rev > `2018.6.29.30914`).